# Array IndexError

Tags: python, arrays

I want to reverse an array 'ar' by using another array 'br' but it gives an IndexError! I don't know why can you help please !

```
# Reversing array
from array import*

ar = array('i', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
br = array('i',[])

d = len(ar)-1
print(d)
for i in ar:
    br[d] = i
    d = d-1
print(br)
```

Comment: you better use python `list` instead of array, you get indexerror cause `br` is empty and does not have `[d]` index, you need to append the value to the list/array rather than to assign by index

Comment: @PYPL How would using a list help?

Comment: ok but can you tell me why it gives indexerror please

Comment: @Icewizard they did tell you, because `br` is empty, and you try to use indexed assignment, `br[d] = i`, no matter the value of `d`, it will always raise an `IndexError`, and in general, if you index passed the size of the array, it will raise an IndexError. That's *what an index error means*

Comment: Thanks for resolving doubts !

Answer (score 2):

Array `br` is empty so you need to do `br.append(i)` instead of `br[d] = i`.
Note that the array can be reversed with [reverse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.reverse).